# Undefined index: log_path in /

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, undefined-index

When i share a post with my app i got this issue:

Notice: Undefined index: log_path in /tjgnsdl1234/www/system/core/Log.php on line 118 Notice: Undefined index: log_path in /tjgnsdl1234/www/system/core/Log.php on line 118 Warning: mkdir(): Invalid path in /tjgnsdl1234/www/system/core/Log.php on line 122 Notice: Undefined index: log_threshold in /tj...

For some reason when I share the image (link) of where the post is supposed to be, the image is seen but it also shows an error. This used to work properly, I must also note that some people do not see the image.

I already tried changing the config.php file and autoload.php file but no one works.

-

Notice: Undefined index: log_path in /tjgnsdl1234/www/system/core/Log.php on line 118 Notice: Undefined index: log_path in /tjgnsdl1234/www/system/core/Log.php on line 118 Warning: mkdir(): Invalid path in /tjgnsdl1234/www/system/core/Log.php on line 122 Notice: Undefined index: log_threshold in /tj...

Now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLI5I.jpg
Before: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mu2SR.jpg

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and make necessary changes

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error, if i remind me right i think your config.php doesn't contain all config vars that CI3 needs.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the similar notice when I run an application. The application is developed with CI3. The application developer shared the application with me to develop some part of the application.

I have installed it and I have found this error/notice when I install it into my development PC.

I have figured the issue out like the following way.

> I have checked the config file under the application/config folder.
> Then I have found there is already `$config['log_path']` exist in it. And I have found the composer_autoload like this
>
> `$config['composer_autoload'] = CDN . 'vendor/autoload.php';`
>
> But the CDN constant is not created
> anywhere. So I have removed the CDN constant and the error is gone.
> I have communicated with the develop and he said, yes, that CDN constant
> is unnecessary.

So I have got the solution like this

From here

`$config['composer_autoload']    = CDN . 'vendor/autoload.php';`

To this

`$config['composer_autoload']    = 'vendor/autoload.php';`

Based on this, I think, this error occurs from the `config file`. Either if there is any mistake of existing variables or if any required variable is missing in the config file.

So, In my opinion, if you get this error, please cross-match your config file with the CodeIgniter-3 config file. I hope, you will find the solution.